# Spring MVC - WARN [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/foo/bar/baz/rest] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-rest'

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, controller

I am running Spring MVC on JBoss app server.

File: jboss-web.xml :

```
 <jboss-web>
            <context-root>/foo/bar/baz</context-root>
        </jboss-web>
```

Context root is defined as /foo/bar/baz something I can't change.

File: web.xml:

```
<servlet>
                <servlet-name>spring-rest</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>spring-rest</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
```

It has the dispatcher servlet mapped to url "/"

Java: (Controller)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            @ResponseBody
            public SomeResponse processRequest(@RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest)
            {
              return someResponse;
            }
```

I am trying to process the request in this method.

When Spring gets loaded in JBoss, I see the following:
[

```
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/rest/*] onto handler 'MyController'
[DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/rest/*.*] onto handler 'MyController'
[DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/rest/*/] onto handler 'MyController
```

'

I try to access: http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/baz/rest, what I see is:

WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/foo/bar/baz/rest] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-rest'

But when I change value to "/*" from "/rest/*" in Java as :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

It then works fine.How do I fix the problem?

spring-rest-servlet.xml:

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
                <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value = "true" />
            </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to have both `/rest` and `/rest/*` handled by single method, use:

```
@RequestMapping(value={ "/rest", "/rest/*" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

it works, because it accepts everything after `/foo/bar/baz`, not only `/rest`